# Как осуществить поиск значения во вложенных массивах?

Tags: php

Есть код который получает от ВК лонг-пулом соответствующие данные в JSON-е. После json_decode у нас получается массив:
(Вот его print_r)

> stdClass Object ( [ts] => 1843599983 [updates] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => -142578342 [2] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 277292865 [2] => 537091 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 537092 [2] => 1 [3] => 277292865 [4] => 1491849931 [5] => ... [6] => Олоооп [7] => stdClass Object ( ) ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 80 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 ) ) )

Как найти определенное значение во вложенном массиве не зная его точного адреса?

Вот код:

```
$ts = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `var` FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1" ));
$ts = $ts['var'];
$kek = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://newimv4.vk.com/nim0304?act=a_check&key=35175cb798dae0fa77671dcf0bce35e7efb30&ts='.$ts.'&wait=90&mode=2&version=1'));
$ts = $kek -> ts;
mysql_query("UPDATE `settings` SET `var` = '".$ts."' WHERE `settings`.`id` = 3;") or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error());
print_r($kek);
$num = array_search('4',($kek->updates));
print_r($num);
```

array_search ничего не находит, при том что это значение там есть. Хэлп)

Comment: ну во первых добавьте второй параметр `true` и вывод

Comment: @Naumov Можно подробней?

Comment: `mysql_*` **Внимание**
Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ для получения более подробной информации.  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @Naumov зачем true? чем вам объекты не угодили?

Answer (score 1):

array_search не умеет искать рекурсивно в многомерном массиве, ищет только в первом ряду значений.
Для рекурсивного поиска в примерах к функции array_search в официальной доке есть хороший пример: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php#91365

Comment: `stdClass Object ( ` смотрите в вопросе в вывод дампа это массив по вашему?

Comment: Вы ищете в свойстве $kek->updates, а он является массивом - разве не так?
Если хотите, чтобы всё было массивом, то воспользуйтесь советом @Darlanar и укажите в json_decode второй параметр как true. За подробной информацией обратитесь к [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)